# How to get string in a Text using regex in Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to get `/data/user/0/com.example.notes/app_flutter/image_picker8474259280565710843.jpg` this in dart (Flutter).

I have tried the below code.

```
var opDataString = '{image: /data/user/0/com.example.notes/app_flutter/image_picker8474259280565710843.jpg}';

print(opDataString.split(new RegExp(r"{image: ^}*$"))[0]);
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using split, you can match using a capture group

```
{image: ([^}]+)}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lVAAtX/1) | [Dart demo](https://ideone.com/f4TwoA)

For example

```
var opDataString = '{image: /data/user/0/com.example.notes/app_flutter/image_picker8474259280565710843.jpg}';
RegExp r = new RegExp("{image: ([^}]+)}");
var match = r.firstMatch(opDataString);
print(match.group(1));
```

Output

```
/data/user/0/com.example.notes/app_flutter/image_picker8474259280565710843.jpg
```

Or using split, getting the second item:

```
print(opDataString.split(new RegExp(r"{image: |}"))[1]);
```

Comment: if you use above example with this answer, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Mahi You might split on for example `print(opDataString.split(new RegExp(r"{image: |}"))[1]);` but a match would be more accurate for the data structure. See https://ideone.com/t1fpDW

Comment: is there any tutorial or links you can provide, google search won't  give me these type of results

Comment: About the groups, for example these pages https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html or https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html. The function is listed at https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/RegExp-class.html